# Hibernate 5 UserType

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, h2

```
@Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        try {
            Object dbResult = rs.getObject(names[0]);
            if (dbResult != null) {
```

when using Hibernate 5 to convert JSON to Java JSON object  in UserType class method `public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names…`
-> why is an array of `String`s `names` used here when just one name is coming?

Comment: To be open to use UserTypes for more than one column?

Answer (score 1):

The reason an array of strings "names" is used in this Hibernate method even when only one name is expected is because Hibernate designed a consistent method signature that can handle both simple cases with one name and more complex cases with multiple names.

If you want only one below is an example:

`String columnName = names[0];`